# resize dinamically height table when move a cursor on <tr>

Tags: html, css

I was thinking if could be a solution for resizing the height table when moving mouse cursor on the table with css hover because  when i'm trying to move the cursor on the following row...the table flickering...end i tought that resize also the height's table when start  hover could  resolve the flickering problem...leterally i was asking my self if were possibile to add another class in `tr:hover + #test {...}` for changing dinamically the height of the table without use scss or less.

here my example link  -->https://jsfiddle.net/7z4b8s63/2/

css

```
table,tr,  td { 
border: 1px solid black;
}
#classTest{
    display: none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
tr:hover + #classTest{
    display:table-row;
    /* z-index: 1;  */
    transform: scale(1); 

    width: 100%
}
```

html

```
  <table style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed"  >
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td>TEST </td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td> TEST</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="test" class="classTest">
                                    <td >A</td>
                                    <td>B</td>
                                    <td>C</td>
                                    <td>D</td>
              <tr>
                                    <td>E</td>
                                    <td>F </td>
                                    <td>G</td>
                                    <td>H </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="test1" class="classTest1">
                                    <td >I</td>
                                    <td>L</td>
                                    <td>M</td>
                                    <td>N</td>
              </tr>
                   <tr>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td>TEST </td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td>TEST </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="test2" class="classTest2">
                                    <td >O</td>
                                    <td>P</td>
                                    <td>Q</td>
                                    <td>R</td>
              </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

*EDIT FOR IMPROVING QUESTION

Comment: Right, and what's your question? What's happening currently?

Comment: currently when moving cursor on  row's table with the function css hover is displayed the under row...i'd like also to resize  a eighth's table...because when i'm trying to move the cursor on the following row...the table flickering...end i tought that resize also  the height's table when start css hover could be resolve the flickering problem.

Comment: Your test code doesn't produce the results you are experiencing - too many errors. First, in your CSS you have `#test`, but there are no `ids` in your HTML, just classes. That's just one of the issues.

Comment: @disinfor i was improved the question...now do how is expected for the problem mentioned.

Comment: @Utkanos please could you delete the negative feedback?...i improved the question.

Comment: You still have multiple `ids` in your HTML. You should change those to `classes` and update the CSS.

Comment: @disinfor here you are have changed everythings.

Comment: @disinfor thanks mate.

Comment: @Utkanos please could you delete a negative feedback?..i'm tryied to improve  my question  as much as possible that i've done.

Comment: @Markus I won't delete the comment as it's part of the narrative showing how this question unfolded, but I have revoked my downvote.

Comment: @Utkanos sorry what is not clear?...tell me...end i'll try to improve

Comment: You cannot do this with css alone - the flickering is caused because when you hover on the shown tr, you are no longer hovering on the hover tr that initiated the show - therefore it disappears again

Comment: @markus - the question IS now clear; I was just replying to your comment about removing the negative feedback which, by revoking my downvote, I have now done.

Comment: @Pete it's ok...but would  you known a potential solution for risolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do anything. This keeps the same size.
    transform: scale(1)

Please try this:

```
td:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

This resizes the td element with 10%

Comment: i'd want to resize table height  together at row displayed.